# bash script not writing into a file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write bash script that can be launched with operational arguments and based on that either append, delete or overwrite data file, but when I use -a or -o arguments, the file stays empty or only white characters. What is the problem? Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/home/xxx/file.data
while getopts 'hadov' CHOICE; do
case "$CHOICE" in
h)      echo "-h (help)">&2
        echo "-a (append)">&2
        echo "-d (delete)">&2
        echo "-o (overwrite)">&2
        echo "-v (view)">&2;;
a)      echo $OPTARG >> $FILE;;
d)      if [ -f $FILE ]; then rm $FILE; else echo "file does not exist" > /dev/null;fi;;
v)      if [ -f $FILE ]; then cat $FILE; else echo "file does not exist" > /dev/null;fi;;
o)      echo $OPTARG > $FILE;;
?)      echo bad opt – ${CHOICE} > /dev/stderr
        echo bad choice, use -h for help >&2
        exit 1;;
esac
done
if [ $OPTIND -eq 1 ];
then
echo "no choice, use -h for help" >/dev/stderr;
exit 1;
fi;
```

Comment: Could you show an example of how you call your script ?

Comment: That means `$OPTARG` is empty.  What else do you expect?

Comment: @Nic3500 According to the help menu, i think he expects that the passed argument value will be written into the file

Comment: What is the purpose of `echo "file does not exist" > /dev/null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getopts` command has the wrong syntax.
You must seperate the optional arguments with a `?`, if you don't expect a argument value, and `:` if you expect a argument value.
So your code with `while`-line replaced with this

```
while getopts 'h?a:d?o:v' CHOICE; do
```

and `./<Script> -o test` will produce a file with `test` in it.

For more information, i would suggest you to read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/optarg)